# Laravel Routing and Components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Hi im new to Laravel and ReactJS, i have a question i think its about Routing.
why i always get redirected to localhost:8000/login.

This is my Routes in web.php:

[image]

and also where is this refering to?

```html
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

My Homecontroller contains the following code:

```
public function __construct() { 
    $this->middleware('auth'); 
} 

public function index() { 
    return view('home'); 
}
```

Comment: When you go to localhost:8000/ you're redirected to /login? What in your HomeController under the method `index`. We need more code to help you.

Comment: sorry yes i dont know about this HomeController under the method index. i only add auth using php artisan make:auth

Comment: Navigate to app/Http/Controllers, open HomeController and update your question with  what's in it.

Comment: Please post the contents of your `app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php` file. It might also be worth posting your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file as well.

Comment: `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }`

Comment: thats what inside my homecontroller.php sir

Comment: Remove the $this->middleware(‘auth’)

Comment: You’re being redirected to the login page because you’ve added the `auth` middleware to your home controller, which says, “Only allow access if the user is authenticated”. Remove that middleware if you want everyone to be able to access your home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of your controller contains a middleware, specifically the auth middleware.
Laravel uses [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) to handle requests.

The auth middleware makes sure that everybody viewing the requested page is logged in.
You are probably viewing the page as a unauthenticated user.

You could either try removing the middleware (removing the `__construct` function) or creating an account and logging in.

Information about routing can also be found [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing).

But in short, your routes file contains all valid urls for your application `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');` means, if anybody comes across the url `example.com/` go to `HomeController` and look at the function `index` to see what to do.

In your case it returns the view `home`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel docs.

> Redirecting Unauthenticated Users
> When the auth middleware detects an unauthorized user, it will either return a JSON 401 response, or, if the request was not an AJAX request, redirect the user to the login named route.
>
> You may modify this behavior by defining an unauthenticated function in your  app/Exceptions/Handler.php file:

That said, you have probably issued a command `php artisan make:auth` which created default views and routes for authentication.
You can list all your routes with `php artisan route:list`

You are getting redirected to login because you are not authenticated (logged in).